# php 5.3 cUrl / linux cmd cURL https

Tags: php, linux, ssl, curl, https

I have a problem setting up a https connection using cURL in php.
here is my php code to set up the connection.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endlocation);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $certificate);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $portNumber);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

the folowing var are:

```
$endlocation = "https://lms.lifeline.nl/mailwebservice/inline/"
$data = json encoded data
$certificate = true path to .crt file
$portNumber = 443
```

when i execute the cURL my page breaks and i get a page error of the compound was reinitialized. as it happens to be i get back a false from the curl_exec.

how ever if i use this file not to directly set up a connection true php but by using linux command line on the same server:

```
$url = "https://lms.lifeline.nl/mailwebservice/inline";
exec("curl $url", $output, $status);
print_r($output); die;
```

then i do get a response back. is there somthing wrong whit my cURL exec in php format?. or is there somthing else that i need to look in to?

Comment: CURLOPT_CAINFO: manual says: only makes sense combined with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER. (And that one is available / changed since php 7.1)

Comment: both removing the CURLOPT_CAINFO and adding CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false/true gets me the same result

Comment: and was say `echo curl_error($ch); `

Comment: well thats part of the problem curl_error only works after the curl_exec how ever my php code does not get past that part

Comment: `if(!$result = curl_exec($ch)) { echo curl_error($ch); } `does not work for you?

Comment: no the curl_exec line generates the error page The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. and it stops the rest of my php file